# give everyone right to folder using command line

Tags: command-line

i don't know how to assign the everyone right to folder. my application give me error if folder does not have the everyone right. so can any one give me some example how to assign the everyone right to folder. i want to do this using .bat file.

can anyone give me some way?

Comment: this could possibly be better on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I have found something in the line of the following (I'm using Users since i'm on a machine with XP)

```
cacls c:\mytestfolder /G Users:F
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need.

```
sudo chmod 777 <Dir Name>
```

Depending if everyone id allowed to write and execute

but it's not advised

```
sudo chmod 444 <Dir Name>
```

For everyone to read

Assuming you are using linux that is, you can put in a shell script to execute multiple commands

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using windows since you want a .bat file?

If that's correct, you'll want to use the "cacls" command: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i want to apply permission in folder not in the file dude.

Comment: That command actually handles permissions for files and folders.